# robot self model filter for depth sensor in ros hydro

Tags: ros, filter, ros-hydro, sensor, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am using ros hydro and my os is ubuntu 12.04 32bit. I want to know if there are suitable depth sensor filters in ros hydro which can filter out the points colliding with the robot self parts based on the robot model (e.g., through urdf file). Currently I am using a footprint filter for 2D laser scanner, and it seems to work fine, but I do know if there is such kind of filter for 3D sensor, e.g., kinect. And also in ros hydro, things are changing, so I would like just to ask.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions and helps!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69004/robot-self-model-filter-for-depth-sensor-in-ros-hydro/) by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, there is a self filter. You need to create a moveit package for your robot and then create a sensors_rgbd.yaml in your moveit config folder.

sensors_rgbd.yaml:

```
sensors:
  - sensor_plugin: occupancy_map_monitor/PointCloudOctomapUpdater
    point_cloud_topic: /kinect/depth_registered/points
    max_range: 4.0
    frame_subsample: 1
    point_subsample: 10
    shape_padding: 0.03
    shape_scale: 1.0
    filtered_cloud_topic: filtered_cloud
```

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-05-21**:
what do you mean by "create a moveit package"? Do I need to install the entire MoveIt? Is it possible to just take it out from MoveIt?

**Comment by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on 2014-05-29**:
The Point Cloud Octomap Updater is a MoveIt plugin. Why would you not like to use MoveIt?

**Comment by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on 2014-05-29**:
Because I don't want to install the full moveit! framework for just one functionality, I have limited hardware and I want to keep things as simple as possible.